# Turning sequences into plots in R

Tags: r, plot

Say I have some sequence consisting of 2 numbers:

```
seq <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Assume I'd want to plot this into a graph in the following way:

My graph (x, y) starts in (0, 0) and has one straight line to (1, 0).
Then, the sequence comes in action:
If the number is a 0, I turn left with 1 coordinate, if the number is a 1, I turn right with 1 coordinate.
So for the example sequence, I start with:

`(0, 0) -> (1, 0) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 0) etc.`

It's better to draw this if you want a good idea of what I mean with turning left and right.

How would I get these points into a plot? Any tips?

Plot example of the sequence:
[image]

Comment: So your sequence never makes the line go up and the path overlaps?

Comment: @avid_useR I recommend you to draw the points I gave here in a graph. You'll understand what I mean. If you follow the path from the line, the turning left and right makes sense.

Comment: Add a desired plot to make it clear, even if it is hand-drawn

Comment: @d.b Added the start of the plot, hope it helps to understand,.

Comment: Why don't you write code to transform your vector to a set of (x,y) coordinates which are easy to plot (I guess)?

Comment: What you are asking for is to implement a small finite state machine.No matter what point you are at, you are going to add one of the vectors (0,1), (1,0), (-1,0) or (0, -1). Which vector you add depends on the previous vector added and the 0-or-1 from the sequence. For instance, if you just added (0,1) then if the next item in the sequence is a 0 you next add (1,0) , i.e. left turn from (0,1) OR if it was 1 you add (0,-1) , right turn)

Comment: @U.Windl Any tips on doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
m = cbind(x = c(0, 1),
          y = c(0, 0))
flag_xy = 1  #Track whether to add to x- or y- coordinate
for (i in x){
    flag_direction = diff(tail(m, 2))  #Track which way the line is facing
    if (i == 0){
        if (flag_xy == 1){
            m = rbind(m, tail(m, 1) + c(0, flag_direction[,1] * 1))
        } else{
            m = rbind(m, tail(m, 1) + c(flag_direction[,2] * -1, 0))
        }
        flag_xy = flag_xy * -1
    } else{
        if (flag_xy  == 1){
            m = rbind(m, tail(m, 1) + c(0, flag_direction[,1] * -1))
        } else{
            m = rbind(m, tail(m, 1) + c(flag_direction[,2]* 1, 0))
        }
        flag_xy = flag_xy * -1
    }
}
graphics.off()
plot(m, asp = 1)
lines(m)
```

[image]

```
m
#     x  y
#     0  0
#     1  0
#[2,] 1  1
#[2,] 2  1
#[2,] 2  0
#[2,] 1  0
#[2,] 1 -1
#[2,] 2 -1
```